# How to store access tokens in Firebase back-end?

Tags: firebase, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions

My React app uses Firebase Authentication and the Real-Time Database. I now need to access 3rd party services using OAuth 2.0. To do this securely, I am using the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with Firebase Functions as my back-end:

1. React app gets an Authorization Code from the 3rd party.
2. Authorization code is passed to a Firebase function to get an access token.

But this is where I am stuck. How do I save the access token in the backend so that the React app can access the 3rd party resources? I don't want to store the access token in the React app because that's not secure.

1. How do I maintain a session in the back-end using Firebase Functions?
2. Should the session be tied to the React app instance or the Firebase user? The former approach would require a session cleanup. The latter has the advantage that new access tokens can be obtained using a refresh token. This way the user never has to login to the 3rd party again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying bunch of different approaches, I ended up storing the access token & the refresh token in the back-end, both tied to the firebase user. The tokens are only accessible through firebase functions. This approach has the following advantages:

1. Secure
2. I don't have to worry about sessions and session cleanup.
3. I can refresh the access token whenever I want using the refresh token.

Answer (score 1):

**OVERALL FACTORS**

Typically these are the areas that your SPA Security choices influence, and there are trade offs:

- Type of App
- Strong Security
- Hosting and Global Performance
- Technical Simplicity

**IN ALL CASES**

Your app should:

- Maintain a token for each user separately
- You will want to identify users from tokens after login

**OPTION 1: FRONT END MODEL / COOKIELESS**

This involves using tokens in the browser and has these benefits:

- Back end is static content only
- Web resources can be deployed close to users via a CDN
- You can use the [OIDC Client library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) to manage security

This is widely used and should only be exploitable if your app has cross site scripting vulnerabilities. Some resources of mine:

- [SPA Goals](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/08/goal-1-spas/)
- [In Memory Authentication Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Code Sample Write Up](https://github.com/gary-archer/authguidance.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts)

**OPTION 2: BACK END MODEL / AUTH COOKIES**

This involves proxying via a back end and carrying tokens around in authentication cookies. I would use this model if developing an online banking app but for medium security apps it can add a lot of overhead. You may have to write more security code and it is possible to end up with a less secure solution than option 1:

- Requires a proxy back end that runs code
- The back end code may need to be clustered and globally distributed, to achieve good performance
- You need to protect the auth cookie and deal with cross site request forgery risks

Out of interest the respected [mod_auth_openidc](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc) library can be helpful for this type of solution.

**BEST OF BOTH WORLDS**

If using tokens in a browser is deemed unacceptable I would aim to follow option 1 as much as possible. Then implement option 2 as an additive step:

- Deploy web static content separately to the code that does back end token management
- Continue to use the OIDC Client library, and make the Authorization Code Exchange call your back end
- The only difference to option 1 is that tokens are not available to browser code

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks so much for your response and the writeup. I will definitely go through it. At the moment, I have successfully implemented front-end based memory storage of access tokens. However, I have read at multiple places that storing tokens in the front-end is not safe (here's [one example](https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/secure-access-token-storage-with-single-page-applications-part-1-9536b0021321). That's why I would like to try a back-end model.

Comment: Very interesting conversation Naresh and you make some good points. I've updated my original answer above with a few extra points on hosting, performance and use of libraries.

Comment: Gary, thanks again for elaborating on your answer. After weighing in all my options, I chose to store the tokens in the back-end. Primary reason being that I was already using the back-end as a proxy to access the OAuth resources (the target resource servers were not allowing me to access them from the front-end anyway - they were giving CORS errors). So it was only a small incremental effort to save the tokens in the back-end.